# XCode 4.3 unit testing C++ library, breakpoints not hit. Why?

Tags: c++, macos, unit-testing, xcode4.3

I have added a unit test target to my C++ static library, in XCode 4.3. The unit test has a type of "Bundle" and is targeted for Mac OS 10.7, not iOS.

When i do "Product-> Test", 
The test fails before with a "test rig" error 139, but I can't debug it since no breakpoints are hit.

Why aren't the breakpoints being hit and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

Well, after trying *all* possible routes, Mac OS X unit tests, iOS unit tests, and even adding application targets to my library, I finally gave up and started a new iOS application, copied all my C++ code to it, and now I can at least debug it properly.

Comment: Are you able to set and hit breakpoints when doing a "normal" run?

Comment: I can't run it "normally" since it's a static library. When I run other iPhone applications I am able to hit breakpoints.

Comment: Sorry to be a bit vague. What I mean is when linking against that library within an application residing in the very same workspace, are you able to hit breakpoints? I really am just poking in the dark but maybe unit-tests and breakpoints only work within "runnable" environments. For testing that, I would simply create a workspace that contains a project for an application. That workspace would also contain your library. Now link that library against your application and run the unit-tests within the app project as a secondary target.

Comment: ...but then again, I guess that is bull as I have created projects in the past that only contain unit-tests and nothing else. Those also worked totally fine including the use of breakpoints.